# Baseboard wiring

Tags: electrical, heating

I'm planning to do something similar to this wiring diagram, but using only 1 thermostat :
[How to Wire 3 baseboard Heaters with 2 Thermostats](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/140079/how-to-wire-3-baseboard-heaters-with-2-thermostats/161598)

Since there'll be too many wires for the thermostat box, I'll use a jonction box between the thermostat and the baseboards.
The wiring will look like this :

Breaker - Thermostat - Junction Box :

- Baseboard 1 (3 ft) daisy chained in parallel with Baseboard 2 (2 ft)
- Baseboard 3 (6 ft)

Please note I'll use a 3750W thermostat.

Just looking for a sanity check before wiring all, thanks for your help!

Comment: Or you can use a larger junction box at the thermostat.   For instance a 4-11/16" square box with a 1-gang mudring will give you enough room for like 6 cables.

Comment: 1 - "daisy chained" and "parallel" are normally different. Do you mean 1 & 2 daisy chained, together parallel with 3? Or something else? A diagram would make it clear. 2 - How many W for each of the 3 baseboards?

Comment: I'm assuming my baseboards will consume about 250W per foot. Which gives 2ft=500 + 3ft=750 + 6ft=1500 for a total of 2750W

Comment: You're right, my description is confusing... Baseboards 1 and 2 will be wired like this diagram : http://cadetheat.com/blog/multiple-heaters-just-one-thermostat/